# How to create an additional attribute in the subclass in python?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, getter

I would like to include an additional attribute to the subclass. I have generated a class Plant. Now I am going to create a Plant_w_ID class which is a derived subclass of Plant. The Plant_w_ID class should include an addition attribute, plant_id, that holds the identifier of each plant. The plant identifier can be passed as an argument to the creation function, e.g. plant =Plant_w_ID('P1') .

I also need to define a 'getter' method in the Plant_w_ID class to retrieve the value of ID attribute accordingly.

May I know how to

i) include an additional attribute, plant_id, to the Plant_w_ID class

ii) and I don't know how to pass the plant identifier as an argument to the creation function. plant = Plant_w_ID('P1')

iii) define a 'getter' method in the Plant_w_ID class to retrieve the value of ID attribute accordingly

Finally, what is the purpose of have a getter method to do so?
Here is the script that is written by me. Thank you.

```
import random
genome_length =50
bases = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']

class Plant:
   def __init__(self):
   self.genome = []
   self.genome = [random.choice(bases) for _ in range(genome_length)]

class Plant_w_ID(Plant):
   def __init__(self, plant_id):
       super().__init__()
       self.plant_id = plant_id

   def add_plant_id(self, plant_id):
       for i in range(len(plant_list)):
       plant_id='P'+str(i)
       plant_list.append(plant_id)

def main():
    plant_list = []
    for x in range (5):   
        plant =Plant_w_ID()
        plant_list.append(plant)
```

Comment: I saw someone answer my question. But where is the post now? Please post it to me again.

Comment: What you expect the function *add_plant_id* to do? It is currentlly done nothing and it will even raise an exception if it will be called.

Comment: I think the add_plant_id is no use now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just inherit from the *Plant* class and add the additional attribute you want like in the following example *plant_id*.
In addition do not forget to call the Plant `__init__` function with the relevant attributes.

The getter can be done is few ways in order to get the new attribute (the following show two examples)

```
import random
genome_length = 50                  
bases = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']        

class Plant:
    def __init__(self):
        self.genome = list()
        self.genome = [random.choice(bases) for _ in range(genome_length)]

    def get_genome(self):
        return self.genome

class Plant_w_ID(Plant):
    def __init__(self, plant_id):
        super().__init__()
        self.plant_id = plant_id

    @property
    def plant_id(self):
        return self.plant_id

    def get_plant_id(self):
        return self.plant_id

def main():
    plant_list = []
    for x in range (5):   
        plant = Plant_w_ID('P{0}'.format(x))
        plant_list.append(plant)
```